# Royal TS PowerShell remote session does not work

Tags: powershell, git-bash

I need to set up a PowerShell entry which connects with the PowerShell of the given server.
I haven't found anything helpful except of [this instruction](http://www.systemcentercentral.com/using-royal-ts-powershell-remote-sessions/).

Instead of getting a PowerShell connection with the desired server I get a PowerShell connection of my local PC.

I also tried the same for cmd.exe and for Git Bash with no success.
I also tried to create tasks, but also with no success.
In all the cases I get the connection with my local PC.

My host system is: Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 Bit
Royal TS: 3.2.9 (Build #60630)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly solved :-)

By External Application Settings for PowerShell:

`Command: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Arguments: -NoExit Enter-PSSession -computername my-remote-server
Working Directory: C:\Windows`

*-computername my-remote-server* was missing, thatwhy it has not worked.

Unfortunatelly Working Directory does not work, I still land in *C:\Users\j.sinitson\Documents*.

Does someone know how to solve that?